# How do I access the ngStyle key and values in decorator?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, decorator, ng-style

I have a list of colour names in my application.

```
let colours = {
  mango: '#e59c09',
  midnight: '#1476a0'
};
```

I want to extend the *ngStyle* directive to be able to understand my custom colour names. I'm doing this by [decorating](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/decorators) the *ngStyle* directive. However, I've hit an uphill battle on the decorator's compile function. I can access the elements' *ngStyle* attribute, but it comes up as a string (understandably). `JSON.parse()` doesn't work on it as it isn't always a valid JSON string due to bind once etc...

I simply want to step-in, iterate over all style keys, and if it contains `color`, I want to check for the value - and replace with hex if it is one of the above custom colour.

I can't seem to be able to access any *ngStyle* internal functions, and the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngStyle.js) is confusing and short; it seems to just set element CSS - where does the $parse do its job? for example, when `ng-style="{color: ctrl.textColor}"` - there is nothing in *ngStyle* source code that is pulling the value of `ctrl.textColour`. Am I looking at the wrong place?

Anyway, how do I access *ng-style* key values so that I can change custom colours to its hex codes please?

This is what I've got so far in my decorator:

```
$provide.decorator('ngStyleDirective', function($delegate) {

    let directive = $delegate[0];
    let link = directive.link;

    directive.compile = function(element, attrs) {

        // Expression here is a string property
        let expression = attrs.ngStyle;

        return function(scope, elem, attr) {

          // How do I iterate over and update style values here?

          // Run original function
          link.apply(this, arguments);

        }

      }

      return $delegate;

});
```

I tried using regex to pull out patterns etc. and inspect elements, but, it seems like the wrong way to approach the problem to me as I then have to manually update string and pass it on to base link function.

## Here's a [plnkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/XahZRRQY2CXmswY67ETy?p=preview).

IF there is a better way to do what I'm trying to do, please let me know.

Comment: Note: This question has been answered, I wanted to award a bounty for the below answerer for an really well written and understandable answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Anyway, how do I access ng-style key values so that I can change custom colours to its hex codes please?

The *ngStyle* property can be re-written within the compile function:

```
directive.compile = function(element, attrs) {
  let expression = getExpressions(attrs.ngStyle);
  attrs.ngStyle = expression;

  return function(scope, elem, attr) {
    // Run original function
    link.apply(this, arguments);  
  }
}
```

#### JSON.parse()

[JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) can be used if the HTML is updated so that the keys are surrounded by double quotes, which means the *ng-style* attribute needs to be delimited with single-quotes (though if one really wanted, one could try to escape the double quotes...)

```
<p ng-style='{ "color": "#e59c09" }'>Hello {{name}}!</p>
<p ng-style='{ "padding": "20px 10px", "background-color": "#1476a0", "color": "#ddd" }'>It is dark here</p>
```

Then parsing that string should yield a valid object, and [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) can be used to iterate over the keys, checking for the word *color*. If the key contains *color*, [Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) can be used to check if the value exists in the *colors* array. If it does exist in the array, then [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) can be used to substitute the value for the variable (i.e. the key in *colours*).

```
function getExpressions(str) {
    var parsed = JSON.parse(str);
    Object.keys(parsed).forEach(function(key) {
        if (key.indexOf('color') > -1) {
            if (Object.keys(colours).indexOf(parsed[key]) > -1) {
                str = str.replace(parsed[key], colours[parsed[key]])
            }
         }
    });
    return str;
}
```

See it demonstrated in the example below. By the way, I had to remove the unused variable *colours* declared within the scope of the function *getExpressions()*, as it was hiding access to the variable defined above on line 3. [Here is an updated plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3ILmvvQyTA1BLkk0C1AC?p=preview).

```js
let app = angular.module('plunker', []);
let colours = {
  mango: '#e59c09',
  midnight: '#1476a0'
};
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
app.config(function($provide) {
  // Extract colour values from the string
  function getExpressions(str) {
    var parsed = JSON.parse(str);
    Object.keys(parsed).forEach(function(key) {
      if (key.indexOf('color') > -1) {
        if (Object.keys(colours).indexOf(parsed[key]) > -1) {
          str = str.replace(parsed[key], colours[parsed[key]])
        }
      }
    });
    return str;
  }

  $provide.decorator('ngStyleDirective', function($delegate) {
    let directive = $delegate[0];
    let link = directive.link;

    directive.compile = function(element, attrs) {
      let expression = getExpressions(attrs.ngStyle);
      attrs.ngStyle = expression;
      return function(scope, elem, attr) {
        // Run original function
        link.apply(this, arguments);
      }
    }
    return $delegate;
  });
});
```

```css
div + div {
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.comment { 
  font-family: courier;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div>
    <p class="comment">--- with hex --</p>
    <p ng-style='{ "color": "#e59c09" }'>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <p ng-style='{ "padding": "20px 10px", "background-color": "#1476a0", "color": "#ddd" }'>It is dark here</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p class="comment">--- with custom colours --</p>
    <p ng-style='{ "color": "mango" }'>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <p ng-style='{ "padding": "20px 10px", "background-color": "midnight", "color": "#ddd" }'>It is dark here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hiya, thank you for the excellent answer. I have one final question. My `ng-style` is used with a controller variable, like so: `ng-style="{ color: ctrl.textColour }"` and the `textColour` so in my `getExpression` function, the str is literally that. Is there a way I can force eval the expression, get the string `mango` out of it, and then apply my custom colour hex value?

Comment: Hmm... So far I have [this example](https://plnkr.co/edit/77xhwsLHoFlKmESDSPvy?p=info) - where the myColour is defined outside the controller and provider, so it can be used in both places, but I presume you would want that style updated whenever the bound controller model value changes... I am guessing a watcher would be necessary to handle that...

Comment: Hm, I won't always know what the variable name is going to be, it could be `ctrl.item.colour` or `ctrl.borderColour`... which is why I was wondering if I could $eval the expression and get the actual item value instead of replacing. Is that possible?

Comment: HI, I just realised that I can call `scope.$eval` from within the link function and it will evaluate the expression and give me the required values instead of variables - that answers my above question. Thanks so much for the amazingly well written answer, I'll accept it soon

Comment: Noooo - I went away on a holiday and wanted to award bounty to this, but came back to see that the other answer has already been awarded automatic bounty :( How do I fix this?

Comment: Given the [bounty guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), I don't believe there is a way to change it, unless you request the intervention of a moderator... I appreciate your gratitude and generosity, though honestly using $parse is likely simpler

Answer (score 3):

Actually, if you want to use parse - and you should - you can use it to parse the expression, replace attributes, and then transform the attribute back to json.

You should use $parse because if your code looks like

```
// in the HTML
<p ng-style="{ padding: '20px 10px', 'background-color': myController.color, color: '#ddd' }">It is dark here</p>
// in the JS
myController.color = 'midnight';
```

Then parsing JSON will not work. You should parse the expression using $parse and call the resulting function with your directive's scope object.

That's why your provider should look like this :

```
$provide.decorator('ngStyleDirective', function($delegate, $parse) {
  let directive = $delegate[0];
  let link = directive.link;

  directive.compile = function(element, attrs) {
    return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      let ngStyleObject = $parse(attrs.ngStyle)(scope, {});

      Object.keys(ngStyleObject).forEach(function(key) {
        if (key.indexOf('color') > -1 && Object.keys(colours).indexOf(ngStyleObject[key]) > -1) {
          ngStyleObject[key] = colours[ngStyleObject[key]];
        }
      });

      attrs.ngStyle = JSON.stringify(ngStyleObject); 
      // Run original function
      link.apply(this, arguments); 
    }
  }
  return $delegate;
});
```

You could also copy the original ngStyle function (instead of calling its link function) as it's pretty simple to add the behavior you expected:

```
$provide.decorator('ngStyleDirective', function($delegate) {
  let directive = $delegate[0];

  directive.compile = function(element, attrs) {
    return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      // here, watch will do the $parse(attrs.ngStyle)(scope) and call the callback when values change
      scope.$watch(attrs.ngStyle, function ngStyleWatchAction(newStyles, oldStyles) {
        if (oldStyles && (newStyles !== oldStyles)) {
          oldStyles.forEach(function(val, style) {  element.css(style, ''); });
        }
        if (newStyles) {
          // instead of just setting the new styles, replace colors with their values
          Object.keys(newStyles).forEach(function(key) { 
            if (key.indexOf('color') > -1 && Object.keys(colours).indexOf(newStyles[key]) > -1) {
              newStyles[key] = colours[newStyles[key]];
            }
          });
          element.css(newStyles);
        }
      }, true);

    }
  }
  return $delegate;
});
```

[You can find the plunker (two versions) here](https://plnkr.co/edit/AJZteyXX71dZZQ7Pjov6?p=preview)